# Liferay pop up iframe issue

Tags: dom, iframe, popup, liferay-6

Using Liferay.Util.openWindow, I am creating a portlet in which another portlet is rendered but after the rendering of second portlet I have to perform some calculations based on the size of Iframe liferay pop up window. The problem I am facing is when I access the element(iframe) using document.getElementById it will always give me null. Strange thing is at that time iframe is present in the DOM,after that when second portlet is rendered completely it can access the iframe element. How should I access the iframe element?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not getting exact issue, you are facing. Please elaborate more

Comment: liferay pop up includes iframe to render inner portlet after rendering of inner portlet iframe object is not accessible but this element is present in dom how to access that iframe element.

Comment: can you try `parent.document.getElementById`

Comment: yes i tried but no success at the end i found the solution with window.frameElement :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using liferay 6.1 then use AUI dialog windows

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/open-liferay-portlet-in-aui-dialogpopup.html

https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/embedding-portlets-in-themes-on-liferay